Nav2 map server - map frame does not exist in RVIZ
I created my custom wheel robot and run it in ROS2 Humble.
My launch file:
import os

from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, DeclareLaunchArgument

from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, PathJoinSubstitution
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

from launch_ros.actions import Node



def generate_launch_description():

    package_name='wheel_bot' 

    rsp = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory(package_name),'launch','rsp.launch.py'
                )]), launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': 'true'}.items()
    )

    # Include the Gazebo launch file, provided by the gazebo_ros package

    gazebo_world = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('wheel_bot'),
        'worlds',
        'test.world')
   
    
    gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), 'launch', 'gazebo.launch.py')]),
                launch_arguments={'world': gazebo_world}.items(),
             )
    

    # Run the spawner node from the gazebo_ros package. The entity name doesn't really matter if you only have a single robot.
    spawn_entity = Node(package='gazebo_ros', executable='spawn_entity.py',
                        arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description',
                                   '-entity', 'my_bot'],
                        output='screen')
    
    
    # Rviz


    # Get the path to the RViz configuration file
    rviz_config_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "rviz_config",
        default_value="map_bot.rviz",
        description="RViz configuration file",
    )

    rviz_base = LaunchConfiguration("rviz_config")

    rviz_config = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [FindPackageShare("wheel_bot"), "config", rviz_base]
    )

    # Launch RViz
    rviz_node = Node(
        package="rviz2",
        executable="rviz2",
        name="rviz2",
        output="log",
        arguments=["-d", rviz_config],
    )

    # Launch them all!
    return LaunchDescription([
        rsp,
        gazebo,
        spawn_entity,
        rviz_config_arg,
        rviz_node
    ])

I run this file with no errors:

I created maps using slam_toolbox:

Next I want to run nav2 map server:
ros2 run nav2_map_server map_server --ros-args -p yaml_filename:=saved_map.yaml -p use_sim_time:=true

and
ros2 run nav2_util lifecycle_bringup map_server

It runs without any errors:

In RVIZ I have an issue: No map received!

But I have /map topic with some data:

So what am I doing wrong and where is my map frame?

Also I put this rqt_graph here, but I'm not sure what I can get from this data:


Did you set the appropriate QOS settings (transient local) in rviz?

Yes, I did, but it not helped.

I can also confirm I am having the same issue on my pc.Not sure what the problem is either: The QOS settings are also the same for me too.
Also, I am using cyclonedds as ros2 dds middleware.
Any help would be greatly appreciated please. Thanks

EDIT
Problem solved:
If the QOS settings are the same and you are using cyclone-dds then the system should work.
In the end the problem was that my Rviz2 was not set to have the "Fixed Frame" at 'map', rather it was on 'odom'.

